# How to fix: Build Monitor View deletes itself randomly

Tags: xml, jenkins, view, config

Im using the build monitor plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin v. jan'17) to create a Jenkins view on a big screen in the breakroom to display current builds. Unfortunately the view gets deleted for no reason after a few days. Then I have to manually recreate the view. I'm using Jenkins 2.176.3.

I had a look in the config.xml file in the jenkins directory on the server. There in the  property the build monitor view is gone. When I recreate the view the config.xml isn't updated. The new view does not appear in the config.xml file. How often is Jenkins updating the config.xml file? A cheap workaround would be to copy the build monitor view xml configuration back into the config.xml file when it's gone, but I want to know the source of this strange behaviour and get rid of it properly. Has somebody experienced the same issue with the build monitor plugin and knows the cause and a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason why its deleting itself, but I found a workaround. If you create the view in the top folder and filter it down to fit your purpose it stays. If you create it it in a subfolder it deletes itself.